# Calculate center point of square from leftMost, rightMost, topMost, BottomMost points using javascript

Tags: javascript, math, rectangles, calculation

I need a help with a formula using javascript to find the center point of a square using leftMost, rightMost, topMost, BottomMost points and the height, width of the square.

[image]

I tried the below code but I'm not getting the exact center point, can somebody please guide me to the right formula?

Thanks in Advance

```js
let leftMost = 100;
let rightMost = 500;
let topMost = 200;
let bottomMost = 600;
let height = bottomMost - topMost;
let width = rightMost - leftMost;
let size = ((width/2) * Math.sqrt(2));
let xPlot = leftMost + (width / 2);
let yPlot = topMost + (height / 2);
console.log(xPlot);
console.log(yPlot);
```

Comment: `but I'm not getting the exact center point` so, *(300,400)* isn't correct? what **is** correct according to your calculations? (hint: *(300,400*) **is** the correct answer)

Comment: To phrase above comment differently, what makes you think that the results you get are not correct?

Comment: @Yunnosch We don't know the 0,0 here, all I know is the values of those 4 points, will it help?

Comment: @JaromandaX the formula I gave is not working in all scenarios, so I assume there is some calculation going wrong,

Comment: please demonstrate a scenario where this fails - I'm guessing not all the squares are parallel to the x/y axes ... not sure why your image has top/bottom/left/right on random parts of the sides though - for a **square** you need coordinates of two opposite vertices - these co-ordinates, regardless of the squares orientation will include the topmost, bottommost, leftmost and rightmost point of the square

Comment: given these two vertices have coordinates `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)`, the middle of the square should be `((x1 + x2) / 2, (y1 + y2) / 2)` - your math is convoluted, but ultimately correct